# Magento2 programatically create coupon code error

Tags: magento2

I have a code I have used in the past. However now I have a cms page that calls in the phtml file and when I then try to go to the page in my browser i just get an error saying "an error occurred while trying to generate this content. Which is not very informative.

I am hoping someone might be able to spot the error (second pair of eyes sometimes help)
I know it is not best practice to use the ObjectManager. I just need this to work and be backwards compatible with something else it is doing later on in this file.  Anyway the error seems to be generated after trying to render the below lines. It is something about the first 3 lines that is triggering an error

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');  


$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');  

$coupon['name'] = "Warranty test code";
$coupon['desc'] = "Warranty Code For";
$coupon['start'] = date('Y-m-d');
$coupon['end'] = '';
$coupon['max_redemptions'] = 1;
$coupon['discount_type'] ='by_fixed';
$coupon['discount_amount'] = 15;
$coupon['flag_is_free_shipping'] = 'no';
$coupon['redemptions'] = 1;
$coupon['code'] ='AUG92022TEST';

$shoppingCartPriceRule = $objectManager->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule');
$shoppingCartPriceRule->setName($coupon['name'])
      ->setDescription($coupon['desc'])
      ->setFromDate($coupon['start'])
      ->setToDate($coupon['end'])
      ->setUsesPerCustomer($coupon['max_redemptions'])
      ->setCustomerGroupIds(array('0','1','2','3'))
      ->setIsActive(1)
      ->setSimpleAction($coupon['discount_type'])
      ->setDiscountAmount($coupon['discount_amount'])
      ->setDiscountQty(1)
      ->setApplyToShipping($coupon['flag_is_free_shipping'])
      ->setTimesUsed($coupon['redemptions'])
      ->setWebsiteIds(array('1','2','6','7'))
      ->setCouponType(2)
      ->setCouponCode($coupon['code'])
      ->setUsesPerCoupon(NULL);
 $shoppingCartPriceRule->save();

 echo "created";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any critical issues with this code, just small mistakes which should not affect to save.

Make sense to emulate environment if you want to apply observers or plugins. Make sense to catch and log/handle errors.

Try following code (I've changed few coupon arguments for verify in my environment)

```php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$logger        = $objectManager->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class);
$emulation     = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation::class);
$emulation->startEnvironmentEmulation(\Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID);
try {
    $coupon['name']                  = "Warranty test code";
    $coupon['desc']                  = "Warranty Code For";
    $coupon['start']                 = date('Y-m-d');
    $coupon['end']                   = '';
    $coupon['max_redemptions']       = 1;
    $coupon['discount_type']         = 'by_fixed';
    $coupon['discount_amount']       = 15;
    $coupon['flag_is_free_shipping'] = 0;
    $coupon['redemptions']           = 1;
    $coupon['code']                  = 'AUG92022TEST';

    $shoppingCartPriceRule = $objectManager->create(\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule::class);
    $shoppingCartPriceRule->setName($coupon['name'])
        ->setDescription($coupon['desc'])
        ->setFromDate($coupon['start'])
        ->setToDate($coupon['end'])
        ->setUsesPerCustomer($coupon['max_redemptions'])
        ->setCustomerGroupIds(['0', '1', '2', '3'])
        ->setIsActive(1)
        ->setSimpleAction($coupon['discount_type'])
        ->setDiscountAmount($coupon['discount_amount'])
        ->setDiscountQty(1)
        ->setApplyToShipping($coupon['flag_is_free_shipping'])
        ->setTimesUsed($coupon['redemptions'])
        ->setWebsiteIds(['1', '4', '7'])
        ->setCouponType(2)
        ->setCouponCode($coupon['code'])
        ->setUsesPerCoupon(0);
    $shoppingCartPriceRule->save();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $logger->critical($e);
} finally {
    $emulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation();
}
```

If you still have the issue, please see `var/log/system.log` and provide exception.

Comment: Thank you what ever changes you made to the code made it work :)

Comment: Hey Victor, how do you know everything about Magento?

Comment: I'm her father, but it's a secret ;)